# Issue in iterating using v-for in vue js and laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am getting some data from the server which looks like this.

[image]

I have some rating data inside of every object. which I want to process before displaying on the screen. So basically i am trying this.

```
<div v-for="item,index in items" :key="index">
//some code 

<span>  {{ processRating(item) }}  </span>
</div>
```

And then in `processRating()` i am just doing `console.log('demo')`

Now if I am not wrong I am expecting in 7 times `demo` to be printed as I have 7 items.

But as you can see in the screenshot, it is iterating 14 times.
But all my data is printed 7 times which is expected. 
I don't understand why this is happening. Any help appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can't tell from the code you've shared, but what I'm expecting is happening is that some async call is getting made, which is changing the value of some other variable in your template after the `items` array is initially set. This is causing the whole component to rerender and thus the `processRating` method would get called again for each `item` in the array of `items`.

Comment: It's better practice to create a computed property (say `processedItems`), which would just be an array of the returned values for each `item` passed to `processRating`, and then you would use that in your `v-for` directive instead. That way, the `processRating` method would only get called again if the `items` array changed value.

Comment: Jsfiddle por favor

Comment: it is maybe printed 2 times because Vue had an update, when printing stuff instead of using console, does it prints 7 or 14 items ?

Comment: @xdrm-brackets, My contents are printed 7 times on the screen which is correct but when i call a function inside of this loop it runs 14 times.

Comment: @thanksd, can you please explain/ show me how to to use computed property instead ? I am struggling this from yesterday.

Comment: @RakeshKohali Maybe take a look at when and why Vue re-renders lists to avoid that behaviour. For performance concerns, preprocess your iterable or make processRating() to run first time and do nothing on next calls.

Comment: @thanksd could you show me please, how I could use a computed property instead of a method?

Comment: Here's a simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/9s6mxpq4/

Comment: @thanksd, Thank you very much. This Worked.